# classical m balls and n bins problem but more tricky

Tags: probability, distributions, conditional-probability, binomial-distribution, expected-value

This is a problem related with the classical $n$ bins and $m$ balls problem but has some modifications that makes it more tricky to solve:

In this case, the probabilities of the bin´s system are not constant but governed by the next conditions:

1. The probability that there is no ball on the whole bin system is given by $p_{nb}$.
2. The probability that a ball goes into a specific bin is not constant but, if we think in the bin's system as a linear array, then, the probability of get a ball in the $i_{th}$ bin is defined by a binomial-like function with parameters $n-1$ and $p_b$ (however this function can be substituted by one of another kind):
   $$P[ball\ goes\ to\ i_{th}\ bin]=0.9*\binom{n-1}{i} p_b^i (1-p_b )^{(n-1)-i}$$
   The 0.9 factor is due to the fact that there is 10% of probability that a ball didn’t fall on any bin and it was out of the system. So:
   $$P[ball\ out]=1-0.9*\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{i} p_b^i (1-p_b )^{(n-1)-i}$$
3. The maximum number of balls that a bin can get is 2.
4. If a bin $i$ has already 2 balls on it, then, the previous $(i-1)$ and the next $(i+1)$ bin can't have a ball (i.e. zero probability of getting a ball).
5. If a bin $i$ has only one ball the previous and the next bin will reduce their chances to get a ball by 70%.

The questions are:

a) What is the probability of finding $r$ balls in the system if the number of balls thrown at it was $n$?

b) Consider that after the first throw, follows a second one, but this time with a number $m_2$ of balls equal to $n-r_1$, where $r_1$ is the total number of balls that were in the bin’s system after the first throw. What is the probability of finding $r_2$ balls in the system after the second throw?

c) (transient problem) What is the probability of finding $r$ balls in the system at a time $t$ if it is thrown randomly balls to the system with a constant rate of $a$ balls/second?. At $t=0$ the number $r$ of balls in the bin's system is zero. (Also remember that there is a chance for each ball to be out of the system)

I really appreciate any idea or hint anyone can give me to solve this problem.

Comment: Do I understand your problem correctly when hitting *any* bin starts with 90% but will reduce in time because once bins are filled the probability of hitting the bins will be reduced?

Comment: yes, exactly @SextusEmpiricus . Once a bin is filled, then the probability of the neighbour bins is reduced

Comment: Rule 5 does it only apply to the previous and next bin or also the the bin itselve?

Comment: What sort of process inspired the creation of this problem?

Comment: yes, @SextusEmpiricus. It also applies to the bin i itself.